# IE 10 Javascript Error not shown

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

- I am newly upgrade browser IE8 to IE10.
- In IE8 any `java script` error occurred it shown in status bar, but
  **IE10** error not displayed in status bar.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Open the developer tools to view the error.

Comment: F12 to open Developer Tools then Console tab

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to "Internet Options"
2. Go to "Advanced" tab.
3. Under "Browsing" header,

   a. Uncheck "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)",

   b. Uncheck "Disable script debugging (Other)",

   c. Check "Display a notification about every script error".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because javascript maybe disabled in your browser.

To enable follow these steps:

Goto Tools drop-down menu->Internet Options->Security tab->earth (Internet) icon->Custom Level button then, Locate Scripting near the bottom of the list->Under Active Scripting->Enable->then hit OK.

now,Answer yes to the following conformation box.
Hit OK to close the Internet Options window.
Finally, hit refresh on your browser window to enjoy the javascript.